# Styling different when HTML is created through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The list item shape is not the same when I write code in HTML and when I write code in javascript. Here is my code in HTML:

```
<div data-role="content" id="list">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a">
        <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="resources/images/th.jpg">
                <h1 class="the-header">Thailand </h1>
                <p class="the-paragraph">
                    Mauris sit turpis, proin est elementum, vel augue.
                </p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

with result :

[image]

And here is my javascript code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += ('<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a" ><li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li><li><a href="#"><img src="resources/images/th.jpg"><h1 class="the-header"> Thailand  </h1><p class="the-paragraph">Mauris sit turpis, proin est elementum, vel augue</p></a></li></ul>');
    });
</script>
```

with result :

[image]

Comment: If you need to clarify the question, use the "edit" link, not not a comment.

Comment: What's different in the "shape"? Javascript doesn't insert linebreaks and tabs, if that's what you mean?

Comment: I suspect you have a widget that reformats elements based on `data-role`, `data-theme`, etc. You need to call it on the added elements after you add it.

Comment: It seems it dosen't read attr of ul "data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a" "  Is that true?

Comment: @Barmar please clearify your solution . How can I make it ?

Comment: Without knowing what widget you're using, I can't answer.

Comment: @adeneo I want to make shape1 with javascript.

Comment: It looks like this is jquery mobile... if so you would need to initialize the widget after inserting it into the dom... something like $('#yourid').listview().listview('refresh');

Comment: @Barmar what do you mean about "widget"?

Comment: Whatever plugin you're using to style the DIV like the first one.

Comment: @NHNick603 Yes its jquery mobile .

Comment: @Barmar I just need to convert html code in javascript . I have taken the UL tag as it is  and insert it into Div id with "list"  . why it is not the same

Comment: Do you have CSS that adds the styling? I don't think so, or it would automatically apply to the new elements. You must be using a widget like `listview`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += ('<ul id="myID" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="a" ><li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li><li><a href="#"><img src="resources/images/th.jpg"><h1 class="the-header"> Thailand  </h1><p class="the-paragraph">Mauris sit turpis, proin est elementum, vel augue</p></a></li></ul>');

    $('#myID').listview().listview('refresh');
});
```

Comment: I'm Sorry Its Working . Its working well . Thank you very much .

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that should change in your code, whether it actually fixes the issue or not:

- IDs are meant to be used only once. Classes can be reused. Please
  change your `list` and other IDs to `classes` so you can create
  multiple elements and style them all under one umbrella.

  - Since you are adding the content dynamically , You can try loading the CSS files again after it.

  `if (!document.getElementById) document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/versions4.css">');`

If these suggestions don't work, please create a `JSFIDDLE` so we can reproduce the problem.